# How to add applications to debug target list from VS Package

Tags: c#, vsix

How to add applications to Debug Target list? My extension should automatically add specific processes to the list. When user selects one, the extension will override the behavior.

Just as an example how it should look: when you create a Web Application you can see a set of browsers.

[image: Example from Web Application project]

Comment: Not used this, but obviously you have tried `More Emulators...`?

Comment: @oleksii sorry for the wrong description. The web application was given just to give an example how it should look like.